# SQLAlchemy generates a different query for counts than expected with a polymorphic_identity

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a query that I create, it looks like

```
items = Session.query(Widgets.id).filter_by(
    state=WidgetStates.NEW
)
```

when I look at the `str` representation of it I see this as the planned query

`str(items)`

```
'SELECT widgets.id AS widgets_guid \nFROM widgets \nWHERE widgets.state = %(state_1)s'
```

However, when I execute the query to get a count with `echo=True` I see a different query being exected:

`items.count()`

```
2014-08-09 11:59:48,875 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
FROM widgets, (SELECT widgets.id AS widgets_id                                       
FROM widgets                                                                           
WHERE widgets.state = %(state_1)s) AS anon_1                                           
WHERE widgets.type IN (%(type_1)s)
```

The problem is that it's going to count the entire widgets table where `type` equals "FOO_WIDGET". But it's not going to filter the count by `state` it as I would have expected it to.

I think the issue relates to the Widget model having a `polymorphic_identity` discriminator applied to it:

```
class Widget(Model):

    class types(object):
        FOO_WIDGET = 'foo'

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': Widget.types.FOO_WIDGET
    }
```

But the issue is it's not using the items query to count, it's using two different tables to get the selected count and one of them does not have any filtering on it. How do I get this query to work as expected?

### Runnable Example

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Unicode, Integer, create_engine, MetaData, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


widgets = Table(
    'widgets', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('type', Unicode),
    Column('state', Unicode)
)


class Widget(Base):
    __table__ = widgets

    class types(object):
        FOO_WIDGET = 'foo'
        BAR_WIDGET = 'bar'

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': widgets.c.type,
    }


class FooWidget(Widget):


    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': Widget.types.FOO_WIDGET
    }


db_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
Session.configure(bind=db_engine)

metadata.create_all(db_engine)

items = Session.query(FooWidget.id).filter_by(
    state='new'
)

print str(items)
print 'i expect the next statement to print something approximating:'
print '''
select count(*) from widgets where type = 'foo' and state = 'new'
'''
print items.count()
# What this actually prints
'''
2014-08-28 09:55:15,055 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT count(*) AS count_1
FROM widgets, (SELECT widgets.id AS widgets_id
FROM widgets
WHERE widgets.state = ?) AS anon_1
WHERE widgets.type IN (?)
'''
```

To run this example you need SQLAlchemy (Tested here with SQLA 0.9.7, in my actual app it's 0.7.x, bug exists in both versions)

Comment: What is `Winget.types`? Is is a relationship?

Comment: No, it's just an enum, I've expanded the answer to show that, thanks for asking.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot replicate. How close is your sample code to the real one?

Comment: @van i added a fully working example script, it should work if you run it directly.

Comment: Indeed looks like a bug when using Single Table Inheritance. Please create new ticket at https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues

Comment: Indeed, I've [created an issue](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3177/single-table-polymorphic-count-issue) on BitBucket. Thanks for the suggestion @van

Comment: This bug will be fixed in the upcoming 1.0 release of SQLAlchemy.